# Store array add handle to variable

Tags: php

Hey in a recent project I got this working and was quite amazed that such a snipped works.

```
$parentRef = &$elements[$targetPath]-> 
    {$contentTypeMap[$contentTypeIdMap[$contentTypeId]]};

if(is_array($parentRef)) {
    $parentRef = &$parentRef[];
}

$parentRef = $element;
```

It was quite intuitive that it might work that way but what exactly is 
`$parentRef[]` returning to make this work?

If I `var_dump` it, i get `null`.

Here is a simplified example which seems to work.

```
<?php

$arr = [1, 2];

$ref = &$arr[];

$ref = 3;

foreach($arr as $n) {
    echo $n;
}
```

This example returns 123 just to verify that it works.

Comment: In short - it returns reference to element of object located in array $elements and if its array it will make it null (but it looks like its bug in code, cause $arr = &$arr[] will be always null, possibly missing index?)

Comment: edited question with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example $arr[] will create new element in array with NULL value. The ampersand is reference to this position, so when you store something to $ref, it will be stored in this new position, because $ref is just reference (something like pointer, but its not pointer!) to this new element in array

Comment: ah cool all that I was missing was that $arr[] actually creates a new element, thanks :)

Comment: its the same as $arr[] = 3; just here you dont provide value directly but later....

Comment: Just usage of references, its quite same to reference using in foreach loop - foreach($array as &$element){ $element = 2;}
This will change content of each element in original array